# Why does this call to NSMutableAttributedString addAttributes crash?

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, core-text

I'm getting a frequent crash on calling `addAttributes` out in the field that I can't reproduce (EXC_BREAKPOINT). Have added checks on the NSRange I'm passing in and surprisingly it still crashes... any ideas very gratefully received!

```
let boldAttributes : [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [.font: cellStyle.boldFont()]
if (nsrange.location >= 0 && nsrange.length > 0 && nsrange.location + nsrange.length <= myAttributedString.length) {
    myAttributedString.addAttributes(boldAttributes, range: nsrange)
}
```

Crash log added by request:

```
#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  MyApp                   0x10054ae38 specialized UIAccessorizedTextField.accessoryAttributedString(IndexPath, cellStyle : UIAccessorizedTextFieldCellStyle) -> NSAttributedString (UIAccessorizedTextField.swift:322)
1  MyApp                   0x10054b104 specialized UIAccessorizedTextField.collectionView(UICollectionView, cellForItemAt : IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell (UIAccessorizedTextField.swift:345)
2  MyApp                   0x10054860c @objc UIAccessorizedTextField.collectionView(UICollectionView, cellForItemAt : IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell (UIAccessorizedTextField.swift)
3  UIKit                          0x18b229f3c -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:] + 356
4  UIKit                          0x18bb90b68 -[UICollectionView _prefetchItemsForVelocity:maxItemsToPrefetch:invalidateCandidatesOnDirectionChanges:] + 508
5  UIKit                          0x18b2088b4 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 760
6  UIKit                          0x18b0d76f4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1420
7  QuartzCore                     0x18564dfec -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 184
8  QuartzCore                     0x18565217c CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 324
9  QuartzCore                     0x1855be830 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 320
10 QuartzCore                     0x1855e6364 CA::Transaction::commit() + 580
11 QuartzCore                     0x1855e71e4 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 92
12 CoreFoundation                 0x18146e910 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
13 CoreFoundation                 0x18146c238 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412
14 CoreFoundation                 0x18146c884 __CFRunLoopRun + 1436
15 CoreFoundation                 0x18138cda8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
16 GraphicsServices               0x183371020 GSEventRunModal + 100
17 UIKit                          0x18b3a9758 UIApplicationMain + 236
18 MyApp                   0x1003f2830 main (main.m:16)
19 libdyld.dylib                  0x180e1dfc0 start + 4
```

Comment: Just remove/disable exception breakpoint and run the project again

Comment: The phrase "out in the field" means when deployed to customers. So it isn't running under any kind of debugger and breakpoints are not active.

Comment: Crash? I guess there is a crash log then. Which is...?

Comment: Nothing interesting or specific in the crash logs on Fabric unfortunately; have added what there is to the question.

Comment: How is calculated `nsrange`? Is it really a `NSRange`? Also, even if you can't reproduce, do you think it could be on "foreign" languages, with different "alphabets", and then a characters length (memory speaking) might be different and cause the issue?

Comment: Could you add more code as without the cellStyle and nsrange declarations I cannot test your code to help you

Comment: As can be seen in the logs, the code crashes because of below in below code


UIAccessorizedTextField.swift:322

Did you check what's there in the line?

Comment: Yes, line 322 is the call to addAttributes shown in the question. More code (with different line numbering) is available at https://gist.github.com/damienlaughton/ef4dd0ad5f6dd52362b2c7100fe0d167?_pjax=%23gist-pjax-container

Comment: @larme that’s an intruiging suggestion... will investigate

Comment: Could you the full code about `myAttributedString` ? Including the creation of `nsrange`? Also, some emoji can cause issues (because their length is bigger that "usual" characters), maybe with forcing the text to be multiple emoji you'll the the issue.

Comment: Hi @Larme, the link to the code on github is just above. Thanks.

Comment: From the Apple docs:
'You may assign any name/value pair you wish to a range of characters. Raises an invalidArgumentException if attributes is nil and an rangeException if any part of aRange lies beyond the end of the receiver’s characters.'

which means, your code could raise an exception only in these cases. Maybe you should check the font what is returned by cellStyle.boldFont(), maybe it's the problem. As @Larme has mentioned there can be special characters which may be not supported by the font you are using.

Comment: It looks to me like this could be related to scrolling elements offscreen and having them destroy while you're attempting to do things.

Answer (score 2):

As the crash is not easily reproducible, it should depend on the contents of `myAttributedString`, or `nsrange`: The surrounding code provides values that pass your checks, but still crash. There are two ways I am aware of how to achieve that.

The first is by passing an `NSRange` that has location `NSNotFound` and `length > 0`. Example:

```
let myAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello")
let nsrange = NSRange(location: NSNotFound, length: 1)
```

The second is a crash in older iOS versions when adding attributes to a subset of an emoji. If you only see crashes in older iOS versions, it should be a scenario like this one:

```
let myAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "‍‍ is a family")
let nsrange = NSRange(location: 1, length: 2)
```

So if you see the crash for all iOS versions, you can check for `nsrange != NSNotFound` first to fix the crash. If you see the crash only for older iOS versions, then check the surrounding code for places where you could calculate a wrong range. This typically happens when mixing string info from Swift with string info from Objective-C's Foundation. For instance, `"‍‍".count` is 1, whereas `("‍‍" as NSString).length` is 8.

Answer (score 0):

First of all need to be sure that `cellStyle.boldFont()` return correct value.
Try to use `UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)` to be sure that you have correct value in `boldAttributes`

```
let boldAttributes : [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)]
if (nsrange.location >= 0 && nsrange.length > 0 && nsrange.location + nsrange.length <= myAttributedString.length) {
    myAttributedString.addAttributes(boldAttributes, range: nsrange)
}
```

After that, double re-check that `myAttributedString` is `NSMutableAttributedString` class using runtime debugger. 
Maybe it is immutable `NSAttributedString` and you trying to add your attributes to it...

After that, if you still have crash, need to check `nsrange` value. Maybe you have `nil` or some incorrect value there